# SpecFlow+LivingDoc in Azure DevOps: Track manual tests

Tags: azure-devops, specflow

Is there any way to track manual tests status in Azure DevOps Living Doc ?

What approach are you using? Tags, etc.?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "track manual tests status in Azure DevOps Living Doc"? Are you writing manual test cases under "Test Plans"? Are you adding a "Tested By" link from the User Stories to the Test Cases?

Comment: No we don't ue Tests Plans.  We use Gherkin language (BDD) for writting ours Tests Cases and SpecFlow for automatisation and Azure DevOps LivingDoc Extension  for generating ours tests cases in Azure DevOps. But we have several manual tests cases that we want track

Comment: The way to do that in Azure DevOps is to create Test Case work items, and link them to the user stories via a "Tested By" link from the story to the Test Case.

Comment: Link to Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/create-a-test-plan?view=azure-devops

Comment: I'm not sure how to include those test cases in LivingDoc, however. LivingDoc is an extension for SpecFlow, which is outside the workflow for Azure DevOps writing manual test case work items.

Comment: Thanks. But, we don't use Azure Test Plan. I tried to find any approch to track manual test with speckflow